# Shnayim Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred and two?

### ?שנים ושלוש מאות - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 302.

Don't just sit there and crank out lazy gematria on this one.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous three hundred and one entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are at a minimum of 302 days in a Jewish year that are not Shabbos. This minimum can only happen in a year that Rosh HaShana is on Shabbos, and the year has 353 days.

Answer (score 3):

The combined number of years that Abraham lived - 175 plus the years that his wife, Sarah, lived - 127 = 302